# Jmeter- HTTP Cache Manager, Unable to cache everything what it is being cached by Browser

Tags: caching, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I used HTTP Chache Manager to Cache files which are being cached in browser. I am successful of doing it for some of the pages. Number of files being cached in Jmeter is equal to Number of files being cached by browser.

But in some cases :
I found number files being cached is lesser than the files being cached by browser.
Using Jmeter I found only 5 files are being cached but in real browser 12 files are getting cached.

Header for one file which is cached in Chrome but not in Jmeter

**Header in Chrome Browser:**

Remote Address:
Request URL:
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Request Headersview source
Accept:image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8,it-CH;q=0.6,it;q=0.4,ar;q=0.2
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:
Host:
If-Modified-Since:Thu, 16 Jan 2014 16:38:32 GMT
If-None-Match:W/"1242-1389890312000"
Referer:
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Wed, 11 Jun 2014 09:57:49 GMT
ETag:W/"1242-1389890312000"
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Server:

**Header in JMeter:**

Thread Name: Thread Group 1-2
Sample Start: 2014-06-11 15:18:56 IST
Load time: 326
Latency: 326
Size in bytes: 1541
Headers size in bytes: 299
Body size in bytes: 1242
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Response code: 200
Response message: OK

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: image/png
Date: Wed, 11 Jun 2014 09:48:53 GMT
ETag: W/"1242-1389890312000"
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 16 Jan 2014 16:38:32 GMT
Server: 
Content-Length: 1242
Connection: keep-alive

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to tick `Use Cache Control/Expires header when processing GET requests` box which simulates real browser behavior and matching content is returned immediately without actual request being made.

Another possible reason is exceeding `Max Number of elements in cache` threshold which defaults to 5000.

See [Using the HTTP Cache Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cache-manager) guide for further explanations and recommendations.

Comment: I have ticked the checkbox for "Use Chache Control/Expires Header when processing GET requests."

I have also tried with Increasing "Max number of Elements in Cache"

Please have look on the header for the file which I have provided in the Query after edit

Comment: I got the Solution which arose another Query.

When I executed the script with 5 Threads I got 5 files got cached. 

But when I executed the Same Script with 1 Thread with 5 Loop all 
the required files got cached same as Browser.

So I am confused with this scenario. Could you please help me.

Comment: If so it may be worth **unticking** `Clear cache each iteration` box so the cache could persist across loops.